# Problems getting (usable) core dump under cygwin

Tags: gcc, gdb, cygwin, coredump

I'm trying to develop code under 64-bit Cygwin, and I'm having trouble getting a core dump file that I can use under GDB.  The code is compiled using GCC 7.3.0, and I've just updated my Cygwin bits.  `ulimit -c` is `unlimited`.

I've got my `$CYGWIN` variable set to point to `dumper`, and that appears to be being launched on crashes.  I get a pop-up, and the message

```
*** starting debugger for pid 5288, tid 9464
*** continuing pid 5288 from debugger call (1)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

and a core file (`basic.exe.core`) is created in the current dir.

When I try to run (the stock Cygwin) GDB on this

```
gdb tests/basic.exe --core=basic.exe.core
```

I get the normal version intro, `Reading symbols...`, and then a warning

```
warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
```

and GDB crashes (and dumps its own core file).  The crashing program was launched from the Cygwin bash command line (as `./tests/basic.exe`).

It's been a long time since I've tried to develop under Windows or Cygwin, so it's quite possible that I'm doing something stupid.  Or, alternatively, it may be that GCC 7.3.0 is doing something wrong or that I configured it poorly when I built it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how you obtained 7.3 .0 ? latest on cygwin is 6.4.0

Comment: I built it from source.

Comment: with all the 26 patch in the 6.4.0 build I assume, correct ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  I didn't do anything special (besides add `--enable-threads`).  It built as `x86_64-unknown-cygwin`, so I assumed that it knew how to configure correctly.  Is there something special I need to do to build GCC under Cygwin?

Comment: Look on the cygwin source package for GCC, it contains the patches and config used. I doubt they are using 26 patches and 20 lines configure just for fun.

Comment: Ah.  I had assumed that any patches needed for 6.4 would have been fed back and would already be incorporated by 7.3.  Some of the patches don't look relevant, but a couple look like they could be.

Do you know if there's a site to get even beta versions of GCC 7 Cygwin ports?  (I need C++17 for what I'm working on.)

Comment: ask cygwin mailing list. May be the maintainer (Jon Yong) is working on it. It is also possible the GDB need an update anyway